# Views and Controllers invisible to each other? How can this be?

Tags: actionscript-3, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I have read that Views and Controllers should be invisible to each other.

How does the controller then listen for say a button click in the UI view?

Surely the controller needs to know about the view to addEventListeners **or** the UI view needs to call functions in the controller, or dispatch events to the controller.

Comment: it's common to use a static dispatcher class for such cases

Comment: ah i see... if i understand correctly that is. so for each view you have a specific static dispatcher, with all the various ui options, triggered by the view ui? that are listened for by the controller or mediator?

Comment: my current mvc is not so pure ^^ we use a static `EventDispatcher` instance so it's possible to broadcast an event that'd be heard by any instance subscribed wherever it is. however imho using `[Bindable]` for things like 'PlayerModel.health changed -> update PlayerHealthBar.value' is a better practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My only experience of MVC is with using the robotlegs framework so I'll try explain my approach when using this framework

My views only use native flash events (MouseEvent.CLICK etc) which are listened for in the mediator for the view. When the mediator receives a native event it will then dispatch an application specific event, LoginEvent.LOGIN for example,  which can be mapped to then fire a command using the command map on your context.

Sorry if that doesn't make much sense, but basically your views fire native events and your mediators will listen for these native events and then fire application specific events which in turn run your commands. You use the mediator as the 'ears' for your view and keep any logic out of them. The application context allows you to fire commands whenever certain events occur so your views and commands are seperated.

Comment: I think I understand - but how does the click listener differentiate between the different ui elements? do you use something like e.target.name (login_btn, logout_btn etc)?

Comment: If you had three buttons in your view you could just fire a different custom event for each button and listen for these in the mediator, or you could examine the payload of the native flash event in the medator to decide what you want to do with it.

Comment: The benefit of using native events is that you could take your view and use it in another project and not have to change any of the custom events, your view is 'dumb' to any project specific events and only handles native events. Your mediator is the only thing tied to that specific project. Sorry probably not the best explanation.